# Changes to one VirtualBox VM Affecting Another

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vhd

For a project, I set up two windows 10 Virtual Machines using VirtualBox from a Linux host. I did so by fully installing Windows 10 on one, then using VirtualBox's clone functionality to make the second. I then generated a unique UUID for the second machine.

My problem is that file changes on the first machine appear when running the second machine. I would like some sort of explanation as to what might be causing this and how to prevent it from happening.

For example, let's call the first machine 'A' and the second machine 'B'. If I create a text document, 'test.txt' on A's Desktop, then shut down and boot 'B', 'test.txt' appears on B's Desktop.

For all intents and purposes, I've made no changes from the base installation aside from installing apps like google chrome.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like they are both sharing the same virtual disk.

The VM UUID is just metadata attached to the VM; VirtualBox regenerated this so it can differentiate between the two VMs.

You should be able to use a tool e.g. [VBoxManage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.1/user/vboxmanage-clonevm.html) to clone the virtual disk and then update one VM to use that cloned disk, which should separate the machines.